# Programmatically modify tags property in files detail in windows using python

Tags: python, file, properties

I want to read and modify the tags in the file properties in Windows. We can see it in the GUI using "properties", "detail" and then the "tags" field. I managed to read these, e.g. http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/get-document-summary-info.html, but I cant find how to update this field.

Comment: [Note: I don't use Windows] So far, Tim Golden (the author of the article you posted) has created a module, winshell, available in [pyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/winshell). With it you can _read_ the structured storage, but you cannot as yet _write_ it (https://winshell.readthedocs.io/en/latest/structured-storage.html#to-do). There's a guide for C++ in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380326(v=vs.85).aspx) in which basically instead of  STGM_READ only (as in the article you linkend) it is used the STGM_CREATE | STGM_READWRITE pair.

Comment: My C++ knowledge is not enough to translate it to Python.